# Our 3d Live wallpaper works fine on galaxy s2 but crashes on galaxy s3 (logs included)

Tags: android, 3d, wallpaper

We've developed couple of **3D Live wallpapers** based on Gl ES 1
There are already on Google Play and **everything was fine until brand new Galaxy SIII release**.

Our wallpapers runs fine on Android 2,3,4 on all devices ingluding all Galaxy family. And Galaxy S2

EXEPT Galaxy sIII.  **It just Crashes on startup**.
So what's the diffenece between Galaxy s2 and s3 ?? **why works on s2 (android 4.0.3) and crashes on s3 (android 4.0.4)**

Here is log (apkname is turtleisle):

07-20 09:07:08.075 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2094): setHidden false

07-20 09:07:08.090 D/dalvikvm( 7968): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.hotpies.turtleisle/lib/libgdx.so 0x418f0bf0

07-20 09:07:08.090 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2094): setHidden false

07-20 09:07:08.100 D/dalvikvm( 7968): Added shared lib /data/data/com.hotpies.turtleisle/lib/libgdx.so 0x418f0bf0

07-20 09:07:08.100 D/dalvikvm( 7968): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.hotpies.turtleisle/lib/libgdx.so 0x418f0bf0, skipping init

07-20 09:07:08.105 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2094): setHidden false

....

07-20 09:07:20.005 I/ActivityManager( 2094): Process com.hotpies.turtleisle (pid 7968) has died.

07-20 09:07:20.005 I/WindowManager( 2094): WIN DEATH: Window{429f06f0 XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX paused=false}

07-20 09:07:20.005 W/ActivityManager( 2094): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.hotpies.turtleisle/.WallpaperService in 5000ms

07-20 09:07:20.010 W/LiveWallpaperPreview( 7950): Wallpaper service gone: ComponentInfo{com.hotpies.turtleisle/com.hotpies.turtleisle.WallpaperService

Thanks!!